# Как ботом отправить ответ в личку?

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется школьный бот для пересылки сообщений из лички учителя в родительский чат.
Как обработать ответ реплаем на пересланное учителем (по сути уже бота) сообщение и отправить его обратно в личку учителю?

Находил `reply_to`, но это ответ самим ботом.

Ещё нашёл аргумент `reply_to_message_id` во многих функциях, в том числе и в `send_message()` - пока думаю как его прикрутить.

Фрагмент кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_messages(message):
    if int(message.chat.id) == int(config.chat):
        try:
            chatId=message.text.split(': ')[0]
            text=message.text.split(': ')[1]
            bot.send_message(chatId, text)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        # При отправке не тем человеком - подставляется его ник
        if message.chat.id == int(config.sender_id):
            sender_name = config.sender_name
        else:
            sender_name = str(message.chat.username)

        bot.send_message(config.chat, f"*{sender_name}*: {message.text}", parse_mode = 'Markdown')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"*{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}*  идет отправка ", parse_mode = 'Markdown')

#        @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
        #def reply_to(message):
        print(message)
        bot.reply_to(message, f"*{message.chat.username}*:", parse_mode = 'Markdown')
```

Comment: попробуйте следующий хандлер `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)` данный хандлер отрабатывает сообщения на ответ, то есть работает только если на сообщение ответили

Comment: Да - заработало! Допилил до `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def reply(message):
    bot.forward_message(config.sender_id, config.chat, message.message_id)` ну и вставить необходимо до обработчика текста )) Спасибо!

Comment: Сформируйте ответ на основе работы которую вы проделали, используйте **Ваш ответ** ниже

Answer (score 0):

Хэндлер

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
```

реагирует на ответ на сообщение, после него можно делать обработку